# Particular Issue - Git - Incorporating Multiple Repositories

Tags: git, codeigniter

I am planning to start a new website and it will use some of my libraries which are newly moved to Git. I have made a post commit hook to Bitbucket and have a PHP deploy script in the root of my web host. My intention is that when I make push, it be deployed to the server. **This question is regarding how I can organize the content & libraries in my website.**

- I have a customized version of CodeIgniter
- I have a few libraries that I need to use (from old projects)
- All of these are git repos but **not following CodeIgniter folder structure**
- My server doesn't have git
- The deploy script is such that it will download the repo and extract it, nothing fancy
- All the sources will be in the `[root]/src` folder

Ideally, I would like to do something like this.

- Go to `src`, do some sort of a fetch from my CodeIgniter library
- got to libraries folder and kind of fetch each library I like to have
- When any of these come to another stable release, go to the respective folder and update

After doing some reading this is where I am.

- I might be able to add a remote to the CodeIgniter repo. When it is updated, I could `rebase`
- I could use git submodules, but it will not deploy the src then (I need the src to be there for deployment purposes)
- I probably can't simply add a remote and fetch the libraries as they don't follow CodeIgniter folder structure

As I understand, the best workaround would be to change the folder structure of the libraries to follow CodeIgniter standards and do a `rebase` when necessary.

Is there any other work around I can do for this?

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to add CodeIgniter directly into your project, you might want to use [subtrees](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html). I haven't used them yet, so I can't recommend them, but they do let you work with a separate repo in a folder, while treating it like it's part of your own repo, committing changes along with the rest of your files. Then you could pull it to a separate branch, rebase or otherwise clean it up how you want, then merge it into your project.

Comment: If I wanted to track a completely separate project while maintaining a reorganization thereof, I would add it as a submodule, then in my own repo I'd make whatever structure I wanted via symlinks. You'd pull latest in the submodule, maybe double-check that your symlinks aren't now broken, `git add CodeIgniter; git commit -m'Pull latest from CodeIgniter'` to lock the current version into your repo, and that would be it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example based on my comments to your original post. In this simple example, I'm interested in tracking the [python_koans](https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans/tree/master/python2/koans) project, but locally I just want a `koans/` folder with the Python 2 koans python files from `python_koans/python2/koans/` in it. In other words, I want a version of the files in my project that does not follow the original project's file structure at all, but I don't want to fight constantly with the structure of the `python_koans` project. Symlinks to the rescue.

```
mkdir myproj
cd myproj
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m'Add empty, initial commit'
git submodule add https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans.git
git add python_koans
git commit -m'Add python_koans project as submodule'
mkdir koans
cd koans
ln -s ../python_koans/python2/koans/*.py .
cd ..
git add koans
git commit -m'Track python_koans locally in koans/ via symlinks'
```

Now you're tracking the `python_koans` project in `python_koans/`, and you have just the files you care about from deep inside that structure symlinked into your project how you want them. In *your* git repo you're tracking just your own symlinks (and the current commit the python_koans submodule is on).

At this point you can make yourself some helpers, like a shell script to `cd koans` and `ln -sf ../python_koans/python2/koans/*.py .` to refresh the symlinks. You could write a bit more to purge stale links to files deleted upstream, and maybe to check overall hierarchy in other ways, or just handle that manually if you trust yourself enough to do so.

Why even make a submodule? You could just pull the latest from `python_koans` to a repo in your home folder, and update things from there into your structure, but you lose the ability to go back in time easily. By making other projects submodules, you're able to `cd submodule_folder; git pull`, then out in your folder `git add submodule_folder; git commit -m'Pull latest from other_project'`, and then you can checkout any point in time later and have the submodule's project roll back to the right time, too, as well as having your symlinks update themselves to that point in time to match up.

Comment: :D That I must say is a cool way to do it, that deserves a distinction... Give me about a day and I will accept it if any thing better won't show up.